# Mysterious horizontal space when using \label after beginning a user-defined environment

Tags: spacing, labels

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcounter{exercise}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise}{}
{
  \refstepcounter{exercise}
  \par\noindent
  \theexercise.\hspace{4pt}X
  \ignorespaces
}
{
  \par
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
  If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then something.
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}\label{A}
  If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then something.
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

Here's the result I see:
[image]

Note that there's extra space after the "X" in the second case. This appears to be caused by the `\label` command. Of course, I'd like it to not be there, but I'm not sure where to begin with diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to delay the typesetting until possibly `\label` has appeared. Assuming these exercises aren't inside lists, the simplest way is using `\everypar`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{showframe}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcounter{exercise}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise}{}
 {
  \refstepcounter{exercise}
  \par
  \everypar={{\setbox0=\lastbox}\theexercise.\hspace{4pt}\everypar={}}
 }
 {
  \par
  \ignorespacesafterend
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
  If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then something.
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}\label{A}
  If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then something.
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `{\setbox0=\lastbox}` we remove the indentation box; since `\label` doesn't start a paragraph, the space after it is ignored.

Possibly simpler: use a theorem-like environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newtheoremstyle{exercise}
  {0pt}       % ABOVESPACE
  {0pt}       % BELOWSPACE
  {\upshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {}          % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  { }         % HEADSPACE
  % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC follows
  {\thmnumber{#2}}

\theoremstyle{exercise}
\newtheorem{exercise}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
  If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then something.
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}\label{A}
  If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then something.
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the case because `\label` was created in such a way that it doesn't introduce a *second* white space after it and doesn't change the spacefactor (a TeX internal variable which specifies how much the current space might be stretched to get alignment, it is set dependent on the last character prior to that space). This is done by `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack`. Unfortunately this ends the scope of `\ignorespaces` as there was a non-space token, and the space after `\label{}` is in fact inserted because there was no space prior to `\label` (else there would be an `\ignorespaces` inserted by `\@esphack`).

The following checks whether `exercise` is followed by a `\label` and if so eats the space after `\label{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\newcounter{exercise}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise}{}
{
  \refstepcounter{exercise}
  \par\noindent
  \theexercise.\hspace{4pt}X
  \@ifnextchar\label
    {\eatlabel}{\ignorespaces}
}
{
  \par
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\newcommand\eatlabel{}
\def\eatlabel\label#1{\label{#1}\ignorespaces}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
  If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then something.
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise} \label{A}
  If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then something.
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. That's a surprise. One more weird LaTeXism, I guess.

Comment: @Derek not so much. Considering the most use cases this is what `\label` and the like (so all those `\@bsphack` `\@esphack` macros) should most reasonably do. You don't want it to eat all the space around it, just not introduce a *second* space.